# CSS3 Form width for different size forms

Tags: html, forms, css

Not quite sure how to get around this issue, have forms nicely marked up in a CSS sheet

```
#forms {
    width:40%; 
    margin: 10px auto; 
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: rgba(144,144,143,0.6);
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #85857f;
}
```

My problem is the smaller forms, two input text box, are looking way too large for the content, anyone know of a method to give different widths to forms that don't involve hard coding inline CSS in the html?

Am quite baffled by this one.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: Add another id or class to your smaller form and add a css to specifically target that smaller form.  For example if you add the class `.small-form` to your other form, you could target that form using `#form.small-form` in css and override your `#form` styles

Comment: By size of content do you mean characters are less?